# Devise/Rails sessions not creating on one server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to migrate a Rails application from one server to another.  The application is working fine on the current server.  I set up the destination server, installed ruby, rails, and postgres.  Then I tarred up the code from the source server and unpacked it on the destination server.  I ran bundle install and rake db:setup.

I can run rails console and see the objects that were in the seed file and interact with them.  I can run rails server and connect to the application.  But when I authenticate to the application, I get redirected to a page asking me to authenticate again.

I am certain that I am entering the right password.  If I intentionally enter the wrong password I am brought back to the same login page that I was on.  If I log in with the correct credentials, I'm redirected to a different page telling me that I need to authenticate.  In troubleshooting the problem I turned the logging level up on the production environment.  When I log in with correct credentials I can see the database query and it updates the User object to reflect another successful login and the last successful login date as current time.

```
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "sign_in_count" = 3, "updated_at" = '2013-01-03
  00:45:19.787483', "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-01-03 00:45:19.786763', "last_sign_in_at"
  = '2013-01-02 22:56:39.395815' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

I also modified the code on the page that I get redirected to so that it will display the words "no user signed in" if user_signed_in? returns false.  I see that every time.  So that implies that the correct username and password are being entered but for some reason the session is not created.

But like I said, this code is working fine on the other server.  Is there some setup step that I might have overlooked?

Further investigation has revealed that the problem only seems to manifest in production mode.  Running the app in development works as expected.

Comment: the dataset which u migrate to the new server also same as the old server ??

Comment: No.  We started with a blank database and whatever data was in the seeds file.